# python bokeh color map array stride

Tags: python, figure, bokeh

I am using Bokeh and I have a fairly elementary question. 
I am reusing the provided example here: http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/image.html which has worked out well for me.

The example code is here:

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import *

N = 1000

x = np.linspace(0, 10, N)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, N)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
d = np.sin(xx)*np.cos(yy)

output_file("image.html", title="image.py example")

p = figure(x_range=[0, 10], y_range=[0, 10])
p.image(image=[d], x=[0], y=[0], dw=[10], dh=[10], palette="Spectral11")

show(p)  # open a browser
```

I have a slightly different data set and I wish to know how to present it to Bokeh.

So my dataset:
It is a 3 dimensional data set consisting of 3 tuples. X, Y and Z. 
X and Y are simple coordinates and Z is a some read back value at this coordinate.

Now the only difference here between this dataset and what is provided in the example is that the datapoints' coordinates do not increment by 1.

X is in the range: `range(-64, 64, 4)` and so is Y

I have a value for Z at each point on the grid like this:

```
[ x,   y,   z]
[-64, -64, 55],
[-64, -60, 56], 
...
```

These points have been turned into the arrays X, Y, Z as previously mentioned.

Now, how do I present this to Bokeh? 
In the example previously mentioned example, we have the line:

`p = figure(x_range=[0, 10], y_range=[0, 10])`
I was trying to give x_range and y_range a list but these attempts failed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got this to work. 
I think I just didn't understand how this type of plot worked in the first place. 
To get this to work I set `x_range` to be `[-64, 16]` and the same for `y_range`
`dw` and `dh` were then set to 128 (2*64).